# Package Manager cannot access repositories but internet is working

Tags: 12.04, synaptic

I am currently at a conference in another country and my package manager cannot access repositories.  My internet is working fine and I can ping the repositories or go to them in a browser, but package manager fails to access them.  If I sudo apt-get update it throws

```
Something wicked happened resolving 'wwwproxy:3128' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

(or Ign's).  This proxy corresponds to my proxy at my office back at home, but I have disabled proxy in the package manager.

Scanning for best repository doesn't work either, it doesn't manage to connect to any.

I have searched for this online and have checked things about my apt.conf file.  My apt.conf contains:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://wwwproxy:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://wwwproxy:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://wwwproxy:3128/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://wwwproxy:3128/";
```

If I remove `apt.conf` (or replace with blank), it makes no difference.  I don't see that it should since I am connecting directly (and have set it so in my network options in Package manager network settings)

I have also tried some things with `resolv.conf` (changing name address to primary and secondary dns) to no avail.  (im not sure if this would help, following other advice)

I am running 12.04.

(I wrote this very quickly and wrote down everything I have tried to possibly shorten the troubleshooting process, have very limited time between lectures and need this sorted asap, my apologies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly `apt-get` (and Synaptic) think there's a non-existent proxy set somewhere.

Try forcing a one-time no proxy with the `-o` option, for example:

```
 sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::proxy=null update
```

and see if that works.

If it does, you can use it for any "emergency" updates/installs.

Note that the `apt.conf` file is obsolete and settings are currently stored in multiple files under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`. To solve this problem, run `grep -r Acquire /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*` and paste the output here so we can help you further.

Comment: This: sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::proxy=null update worked. Yay, thank you so much :)  Just have to add the -o Acquire part to the apt-get install lines for the packages I need as well.

Answer (score 1):

Uhh, it is hard, but I will try to answer...
If you are using proxy, than you must replace the `wwwproxy` substring with your real proxy name. Ex. `my.proxy-name.org` (this is not valid, just an example).
If you are not using it, then delete the `apt.conf` file, and issue `sudo apt-get clean` command.
After that run the update commands as usual. If it is not working, post the full output of your terminal to pastebin to can investigate this issue.

Comment: Not using a proxy.  I removed apt.conf and ran sudo apt-get clean and then update again, same output:

Comment: http://pastebin.atmoner.com/6fbXWq5r

Comment: Ok, paste the content of resolv.conf as well.